# Delphi - In which Uses Clause is 'Self' defined?

Tags: delphi

Delphi Tokyo - I have a standalone UNIT I am using as a utility/library... aka there is NO form associated with it.  One of the routines creates and displays an 'OpenDialog' component. When I try to compile the code, I am getting the error: 
 Undeclared identifier 'Self'.  My code is simple...

```
    var
      ExcelOpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    begin

     ExcelOpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(Self);
     ...
```

This leads me to the conclusion that I don't have an entry in the USES clause that I need, but I have no idea which one I am missing.  My current USES clause is...

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, System.UITypes, ComObj,  Office_TLB, Excel_TLB,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.IOUtils, System.StrUtils, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults;
```

What do I need to add to get this to compile?  When I add the TOpenDialog component to a form, (and it compiles), I find that all the entries in the USES clause are already included in my library unit...

Comment: self is an internal pointer that an object has to itself. You have no object, therefore you cannot use 'self'.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Self

Comment: since you have no owner, just use nil instead of self. Don't forget to free the dialog after usage.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - I thought 'self' meant that it owned itself, and no parent/owner was needed... Regardless, that worked.  Submit as answer and I will accept.

Comment: X := TX.Create(self) means that the current object "owns object X. If the current object descends from TComponent (like a form), X will be destroyed when the current object is destroyed... when you use X:=TX.Create(nil), you are responsible for freeing the object at the right moment.

Comment: @user1009073 `Self` is a hidden input parameter of non-static class methods. Your code is not running inside a class method, so there is no `Self` parameter in scope to use.

Comment: @user1009073: the fact that you ask a question like this shows that you have to learn a lot about Delphi and objects. To effectively use the language you should know a little more about it. Please read the *Delphi* or *Object Pascal Language Guide* that comes with your installation of Delphi. It is part of the help files, but can also be found online: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Delphi_Language_Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already metioned by @whosrdaddy you do not have an object here, so you should use `NIL` as value for the owner parameter.
In this case you are responsible for cleaning up after you are done with the dialog, for example like this

```
var
  ExcelOpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
begin
  ExcelOpenDialog1 := TOpenDialog.Create(NIL);
  try
    // do your stuff here with ExcelOpenDialog1
  finally
    ExcelOpenDialog1.Free;
  end;
```